# Iterating Through Table in High-Performance Code

Tags: sql-server-2005

Supposing I have two temporary tables

```
CREATE TABLE TableA
(
    SomeValue    NVARCHAR(64)
)

CREATE TABLE TableB
(
    SomeValue    NVARHCAR(64)
)
```

and a final table

```
CREATE TABLE TableC
(
    SomeValue1    NVARCHAR(64),
    SomeValue2    NVARHCAR(64)
),
```

what is the best way to insert into `TableC` *every possible combination* of values from `TableA` and `TableB` in a high-perfomance fashion? I know cursors must be the least thing to think about, but will two `WHILE` loops do it fast enough?

Comment: How many rows in A and B? Do you want it atomic/transaction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple Cartesian product which is a CROSS JOIN ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Cross_join), [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190690.aspx))

```
INSERT TABLEC 
   (SomeValue1, SomeValue2)
SELECT
   TABLEA.SomeValue, TABLEB.SomeValue
FROM
   TABLEA CROSS JOIN TABLEB
```