# Inheritance Problem in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, inheritance, join

I am having a problem whose solution I can't seem to figure out at the moment. Say I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE #Test
(
     SomeValue1 INT,
     SomeValue2 INT
)
```

Now, I have two other tables, say `TableA` and  `TableB`, in which `TableB` inherits from `TableA` by sharing its primary key. I want to insert `SomeValue1` into `TableA` and `SomeValue2` into `TableB`, but in a way such that when you join `TableA` and `TableB` by their primary key you get `#Test`, but I can't figure out how to do it. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: What do tableA and tableB look like?

Comment: SQL Server is a **relational** database and not an object oriented database, there is no inheritance, so stop thinking in those terms.

Comment: Are `SomeValue1` values unique?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SomeValue1, SomeValue2 FROM TableA A JOIN TableB B ON A.PrimaryKey=B.PrimaryKey
```

That sounds like what you're asking for, from what I can tell.  Maybe you're also saying you want to create a View on the two tables of existing data?

Comment: No, its not that. I want to be able to make a join in the way I said, but I must store the values in two separate tables independently.

Comment: Could you use CREATE VIEW and the above SQL statement to define #Test as a view that has your requested display of data from Tables A and B?  If not, some background would help as the question is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

If TableB inherits I assume TableB has the foreign key to an IDENTITY column in TableA

```
INSERT TableA (SomeValue) VALUES (SomeValue1)
INSERT TableB (SomeValue) VALUES (SCOPE_IDENTITY(), SomeValue2)
```

Otherwise, you can adapt the OUTPUT clause from your other recent questions: [Output to Temporary Table in SQL Server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6292154/output-to-temporary-table-in-sql-server-2005)

Note:

How does this relate to [Iterating Through Table in High-Performance Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290865/iterating-through-table-in-high-performance-code)? What is your actual end to end requirement... you are asking very specific questions that probably don't really help

Comment: Yes, that's true, but I must insert several values in a row, so I can't use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`.